# Modifying back reference on regular expression (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Getting frustrated...

So, I want to modify the back reference of a preg_replace. Figured I can't actually modify (?) so am wondering if it's possible to change the regex to achieve same result.

Example. Match `[xx_xx]` and output `"xx_xx"` and `"xx xx"`. The `"xx_xx"` is straightforward (as follows) but the `"xx xx"` ?

```
$y = "this [fishing_rod] is bent";
echo preg_replace("/\[(.+?)\]/", "\"\\1\", $y);
// this fishing_rod is bent
```

How do I achieve : this fishing_rod fishing rod is bent ?

(this is just an example, what I'm doing it is more complex !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function

```
function fun($matches) {
        return str_replace('_',' ',$matches[1]); 
}

$y = "this [fishing_rod] is bent";
echo preg_replace_callback("/\[(.+?)\]/","fun", $y);
```

Comment: Perfect. One day I'm just going to read every page in the PHP manual. Not knowing what you don't know sucks. Thanks.

Comment: @Bob: **Not knowing what you don't know sucks** Good one ^^